# Difficulty with non-linear curve fitting

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to fit the experimental data to the following equation:
`(2*π/377)*Sum[S[i]^2*Y[i]*w^2/(W0[i]^2 - w^2)^2 + Y[i]^2*w^2), {i, 1, n}]`.

The data I have is for `n=4` with W0[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEroj.png)=0 and so far, I've done the following:

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/SDzdNXrd", "Table"]
model = (2 π/377) (S1^2*Y1*w^2/((0 - w^2)^2 + Y1^2*w^2) + 
 S2^2*Y2*w^2/((W02^2 - w^2)^2 + Y2^2*w^2) + 
 S3^2*Y3*w^2/((W03^2 - w^2)^2 + Y3^2*w^2) + 
 S4^2*Y4*w^2/((W04^2 - w^2)^2 + Y4^2*w^2));
fit = FindFit[data, {model, {S1 > 0, S2 > 0, S3 > 0, S4 > 0, W02 > 0, W03 > 0,
                             W04 > 0, Y1 > 0, Y2 > 0, Y3 > 0, Y4 > 0}},
              {S1, S2, S3, S4, W02, W03, W04, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4}, w,
              AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxIterations -> 10000]
Show[Plot[Evaluate[model /. fit], {w, 0, 60000}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All,
     AxesLabel -> {"Frequency", "Conductivity"}], ListPlot[data]]
```

And I get an extremely poor fit with this.

[image]

I am very new to Mathematica so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried specifying better starting values for your parameters? You can use the alternative syntax `FindFit[data, model, {{par1, startval1}, {par2, startval2}, ...}, vars]`. See also the [docs for `FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html). Note also that you immediately obtain an excellent fit if you remove the restrictions on the values of your parameters. Most parameters still remain positive anyway, with the exception of `W01`, which becomes small and negative. Only you know whether that is acceptable...

Comment: Hi, negative values aren't allowed for any of the parameters. The problem is even if I start with other starting values for the parameters, one of the sets of values {S, W0, Y} comes out to be very large compared to others, which doesn't at all make sense physically (according to the experimenter who gave me the data).

Comment: Is it possible that the model is not appropriate for the data then? Can you find a set of parameters that generates a shape similar to the data you have from the model you were given?

Comment: Yes, in fact, if I remove the Y in the numerator and the factor (2\[Pi]/377), it fits very smoothly(https://pasteboard.co/HgbCdfo.png). But the person who gave me the data is very clear that the model in question is the right one. So I've been dealing with it for a while now and without much success.

Comment: @NabinBhatta Your fit  is quite good with less parameters. Adding Y's is not a good idea, since it is then you may over-fitting. Always prefer models as simple as possible, i.e. minimum # of parameters with minimum error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem is that there is a massive amount of data at low frequencies and a sparse amount of data at high frequencies making the fitting with linear frequency skewed.

There are 4379 data point. Below is a plot for the first 4329 (black) data points and the data points from 4330 to 4379.

```
ListPlot[{data[[1 ;; 4329]], data[[4330 ;; -1]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, PlotRange -> {{0, 50000}, {0, 8000}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The shape of a function that has the form below

[image: Mathematica graphics]

is a peak whose amplitude is controlled by `S4` and center by `W4`. The parameter `Y4` also affects the amplitude but also controls the sharpness of the peak. See the `Manipulate` below.

Manipulate[

```
 Show[
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50000}, {0, 8000}}],
  Plot[(2 \[Pi]/377) (S4^2*Y4*w^2/((W04^2 - w^2)^2 + Y4^2*w^2)),
   {w, 20000, 50000}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]
  ],

 {{S4, 64455}, 5000, 80000, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{Y4, 43240}, 500, 50000, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{W04, 43240}, 0, 50000, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By playing with the `Manipulate` some reasonable starting parameters were determined.

### High Frequency data

Parameters for the hump in the high frequency were determined in a separate fitting process.

```
model4 = (2 \[Pi]/377) (S4^2*Y4*w^2/((W04^2 - w^2)^2 + Y4^2*w^2))

nlm4 = NonlinearModelFit[data[[4330 ;; -1]],
         {model4, {S4 > 0, Y4 > 0, W04 > 0}}, {S4, Y4, W04}, w]

nlm4["BestFitParameters"]

{S4 -> 64456.4, Y4 -> 43241.5, W04 -> 42416.4}

Show[
 ListPlot[data[[4330 ;; -1]], PlotStyle -> Black, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50000}, {0, 8000}}],
 Plot[nlm4[w], {w, 20000, 50000}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Full Model

I found it necessary to constrain the `W0n` parameters. In particular the late frequency data needed to be constrained to a high value or it would be swamped by the large amount of early frequency data (alternatively using a weighting function related to frequency might be the way to go).

I used the `Manipulate` above to get reasonable starting values for parameters in group 1 and 2 and allowed group 3 to be free.

```
 model = (2 π/377) (
 S1^2*Y1*w^2/((0 - w^2)^2 + Y1^2*w^2) + 
 S2^2*Y2*w^2/((W02^2 - w^2)^2 + Y2^2*w^2) + 
 S3^2*Y3*w^2/((W03^2 - w^2)^2 + Y3^2*w^2) + 
 S4^2*Y4*w^2/((W04^2 - w^2)^2 + Y4^2*w^2)
 )

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, 
  {
   model,
   {S1 > 0, Y1 > 0,
    S2 > 0, Y2 > 0, W02 > 0.5,
    S3 > 0, Y3 > 0, 10000 > W03 > 10,
    S4 > 0, Y4 > 0, W04 > 30000
    }
   },
  {
   {S1, 40000}, {Y1, 6000},
   {S2, 13000}, {Y2, 700}, {W02, 10},
   S3, Y3, W03,
   {S4, 65000}, {Y4, 50000}, {W04, 45000}
   },
  w
  ]
```

The parameters are approximately

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]

{S1 -> 40942.1, Y1 -> 6071.72, S2 -> 13472.8, Y2 -> 759.179, 
 W02 -> 4.52962, S3 -> 354.288, Y3 -> 3.10132, W03 -> 518.807, 
 S4 -> 67601.3, Y4 -> 50274.8, W04 -> 46349.4}
```

Below is a comparison of the model and data

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50000}, {0, 8000}}],
 Plot[nlm[w], {w, 0, 50000}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The residuals (difference between the fit and data) are shown below

Quiet@ListPlot[
  Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], nlm["StandardizedResiduals"]}], 
  PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Full]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Weighted model

A plot of the data versus logarithm of the frequency

```
ListLogLinearPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

makes it appear that the low frequency data is poorer quality than the high frequency data.

Let's try the same fit weighting the data by the log of the frequency.

```
nlmW = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, 
  {
   model,
   {S1 > 0, Y1 > 0,
    S2 > 0, Y2 > 0, W02 > 0.5,
    S3 > 0, Y3 > 0, 10000 > W03 > 10,
    S4 > 0, Y4 > 0, W04 > 30000
    }
   },
  {
   {S1, 40000}, {Y1, 6000},
   {S2, 13000}, {Y2, 700}, {W02, 10},
   S3, Y3, W03,
   {S4, 65000}, {Y4, 50000}, {W04, 45000}
   },
  w,
  Weights -> Log[data[[All, 1]]]
  ]
```

The parameters change with the weighting

```
nlmW["BestFitParameters"]

{S1 -> 40014.8, Y1 -> 7761.67, S2 -> 15067.5, Y2 -> 929.066, 
 W02 -> 361.469, S3 -> 11880.2, Y3 -> 3343.04, W03 -> 2073.73, 
 S4 -> 52602.7, Y4 -> 29854.2, W04 -> 42160.2}
```

The higher frequency data now fits better with a corresponding degradation in the low frequency data

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50000}, {0, 8000}}],
 Plot[nlmW[w], {w, 0, 50000}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Quiet@ListPlot[
  Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], nlmW["StandardizedResiduals"]}], 
  PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped a lot! Btw, is there any way that I can plot the 4 components of the model separately in the same frame so that it is easier to see what constituted the fitted model?

Answer (score 2):

(This answer is not very detailed, I might elaborate it later on... I hope it helps ...)

The data is not evenly spaced across the x-axis so it is a good idea to sample it in a way that produces more uniform x-values distribution.

After this is done, we still do not get good fitting results with all data samples. That is why I made the search loop below. After running it with 100 iterations, a few times I got good fits, like this one:

[image]

Here is the function from one of the those good fits:

```
2/377 \[Pi] ((1.971*10^12 #1^2)/(1.24692*10^7 #1^2 + #1^4) + (
    1.19479*10^13 #1^2)/(7.89216*10^7 #1^2 + (61.0327 - #1^2)^2) + (
    6.63511*10^10 #1^2)/(415362. #1^2 + (135157. - #1^2)^2) + (
    7.35593*10^13 #1^2)/(
    7.93947*10^8 #1^2 + (1.75308*10^9 - #1^2)^2)) &
```

Let us check it against the data:

```
ordInds = Ordering[sRes[[All, 2]]]
nlmFit = sRes[[First[ordInds], 1]]
fitVals = {#, nlmFit["Function"][#]} & /@ data[[All, 1]];

ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 
    1]], (fitVals[[All, 2]] - data[[All, 2]])/data[[All, 2]]}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

And here is the fit and the data together:

```
Show[{ListLinePlot[{#, nlmFit["Function"][#]} & /@ data[[All, 1]], 
   PlotRange -> All], 
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.004], Red}]}]
```

[image]

### Code

```
Clear[GetDataSample]
GetDataSample[data_?MatrixQ, nBreaks_Integer, nCellSamples_Integer] :=    
    Block[{qs, breaks, data2, t},
   qs = Quantile[data[[All, 1]], Range[0, 1, 0.05]];
   breaks = 
    Range[Min[data[[All, 1]]], 
     qs[[-2]], (qs[[-2]] - Min[data[[All, 1]]])/nBreaks];
   breaks = Append[breaks, qs[[-1]]];
   data2 = 
    Map[Function[{q}, t = Select[data, q[[1]] <= #[[1]] < q[[2]] &]; 
      If[q[[2]] == Max[data[[All, 1]]], t, 
       RandomSample[t, Min[nCellSamples, Length[t]]]]], 
     Partition[breaks, 2, 1]];
   data2 = SortBy[Join @@ data2, First]
   ];

sRes =
  Table[(
    Print[i];
    data2 = GetDataSample[data, 10, 10];
    nlmFit2 = 
     NonlinearModelFit[
      data2, {model, {S1 > 0, S2 > 0, S3 > 0, S4 > 0, W02 > 0, 
        W03 > 0, W04 > 0, Y1 >= 0, Y2 >= 0, Y3 >= 0, Y4 >= 0}}, {S1, 
       S2, S3, S4, W02, W03, W04, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4}, w, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxIterations -> 10000];
    fitVals = {#, nlmFit2["Function"][#]} & /@ data[[All, 1]];
    diffs = (fitVals[[All, 2]] - data[[All, 2]])/data[[All, 2]];
    t = {nlmFit2, Max[Abs[diffs]], 
      Quantile[diffs, Range[0, 1, 0.1]]};
    Print[t];
    Print[
     ListLogPlot[{data2, {#, nlmFit2["Function"][#]} & /@ 
        data2[[All, 1]]}, PlotRange -> All]];
    t), {i, 100}];
```

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful.